# SolveAlways: remove trivial solutions

Tags: equation-solving

Dear readers of my question,

I have a function myfun[r] that looks like this:

[image]

I try to solve it for all r, by means of

```
SolveAlways[myfun[r] == 0, {r}]
```

Of course, I want it to come up with

```
EE -> -M e^4 / (32 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 Pi^2)
```

But unfortunately it comes up with 3 trivial solutions, plus the one I want but then expressed as MM -> -32 EE ...

How do I do that?

My code:

```
a0 = 4 Pi epsilon0 hbar^2/(M e^2)
ro[r_, n_] := 2 r/(n a0)
R[r_, l_, n_] := 
 Exp[-ro[r, n]/2] ro[r, n]^
   l Sum[(-1)^kp Binomial[n + l, n - l - 1 - kp] ro[r, n]^kp/kp!, {kp,
     0, n - l - 1}]
rterm1[r_, l_, n_] := 
 Simplify[(Evaluate[D[rr^2 D[R[rr, l, n], rr], rr]] //. rr -> r)]
rterm2[r_, l_, n_] := 
 Simplify[(2 M/hbar^2 r^2 (EE + e^2/(4 Pi epsilon0 r)) - l (l + 1)) R[
    r, l, n]]
rtotal[r_, l_, n_] := Simplify[rterm1[r, l, n] + rterm2[r, l, n]]
Expand[rtotal[r, 0, 1]]
sol = SolveAlways[% == 0, {r}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question and provide code that can be copied and pasted into a notebook for evaluation. An image and missing definition for `myfun` is not helpful.

Comment: One way to remove the solutions that have the form _-> and that looks similar to natural language is `Select[NoneTrue@MatchQ[_ -> 0]]@sol` but be careful with `@` as it looks nice but precedence issues can lead to unexpected behavior. Use parenthesis or explicit brackets whenever the order of evaluation is unclear.

Comment: For example `Select[NoneTrue[MatchQ[_ -> 0]]]@sol` might be more clear

Answer (score 2):

Please post plain text code next time.

To remove all solutions of the form `{a->0,b->0,c->0}` one way is to use cases

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol = {{EE -> 0, e -> 0}, {eps -> 0, e -> 0}, {hbar -> 0, 
   e -> 0}, {M -> -32*eps^2*hbar^2*Pi^2/e^4}, {M -> 0}}
Cases[sol, x_ /; Union[Last[#] & /@ x] =!= {0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This will look at each solution and if it is all `->0` will remove it.

I am sure there are many other ways to do this in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Starting with Nasser's approach,

```
sol = {{EE -> 0, e -> 0}, {epsilon0 -> 0, e -> 0}, {hbar -> 0, 
    e -> 0}, {M -> -32*EE*epsilon0^2*hbar^2*Pi^2/e^4}, {M -> 0}};

sol2 = Cases[sol, x_ /; Union[Last /@ x] =!= {0}]

(* {{M -> -((32 EE epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2)/e^4)}} *)
```

Convert the [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) to an equation and [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for `EE`

```
Solve[sol2[[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal, EE]

(* {{EE -> -((e^4 M)/(32 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2))}} *)
```

**EDIT:** With the function definitions

```
a0 = 4 Pi epsilon0 hbar^2/(M e^2);
ro[r_, n_] := 2 r/(n a0)
R[r_, l_, n_] := 
 Evaluate[Exp[-ro[r, n]/2] ro[r, n]^
    l Sum[(-1)^kp Binomial[n + l, n - l - 1 - kp] ro[r, n]^kp/kp!, {kp, 0, 
     n - l - 1}]]

rterm1[r_, l_, n_] := 
  Simplify[(Evaluate[D[rr^2 D[R[rr, l, n], rr], rr]] //. rr -> r)];

rterm2[r_, l_, n_] := 
 Simplify[(2 M/hbar^2 r^2 (EE + e^2/(4 Pi epsilon0 r)) - l (l + 1)) R[r, l, 
    n]]

rtotal[r_, l_, n_] := Simplify[rterm1[r, l, n] + rterm2[r, l, n]]

Cases[Reduce[{rtotal[r, 0, 1] == 0, 
    Element[{e, epsilon0, hbar, M, r}, PositiveReals]}, r],
  _Equal] /.
 Equal -> Rule

(* {EE -> -((e^4 M)/(32 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2))} *)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
sol2 = Reduce[{rtotal[r, 0, 2] == 0, 
   Element[{e, epsilon0, hbar, M, r}, PositiveReals]}, r]

(* e > 0 && epsilon0 > 0 && hbar > 0 && 
 M > 0 && ((EE == -((e^4 M)/(128 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2)) && r > 0) || 
   r == (8 epsilon0 hbar^2 π)/(e^2 M)) *)

Cases[sol2, (EE == expr_), Infinity] /. Equal :> Rule

(* {EE -> -((e^4 M)/(128 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2))} *)
```

**EDIT 3:** More generally, for positive integer `n`

```
EE[n] -> FindSequenceFunction[
  Cases[Table[
    Reduce[{rtotal[r, 0, n] == 0, 
      Element[{e, epsilon0, hbar, M, r}, PositiveReals]}, r],
    {n, 1, 6}], (EE == expr_) :> expr, Infinity], n]

(* EE[n] -> -((e^4 M)/(32 epsilon0^2 hbar^2 n^2 π^2)) *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions!
Actually, I think the cleanest way would be to "assume" that e, epsilon0, hbar and M are all positive real numbers. But I don't see a way to do this with SolveAlways. Can I declare these assumptions in some way such that SolveAlways takes this into account?

Comment: You have not provided a definition for `myfun[r]` so we cannot investigate anything other than manipulating the output provided.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Bob.
I guess it's best to edit my original question.

Comment: I just added my code to the original question.

Comment: Just noticed the update, this looks cleaner indeed. Thanks a lot Bob! And Nasser too of course. Haven't got sufficient reputation yet to give you points ...

Comment: Unfortunately, the method above does not work when replacing rtotal[r, 0, 1] by rtotal[r, 0, 2].
The Reduce[] operation doesn't seem to be entirely equivalent to SolveAlways[]

Comment: Works for me. See edit 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do `SolveAlways` manually

```
y = Expand[rtotal[r, 0, 1]]
z = Eliminate[!y == 0, r]
Solve[!z, M]
(*{{M -> 0}, {M -> -((32 EE epsilon0^2 hbar^2 π^2)/e^4)}}*)
```

This does not remove all zeros, but the result is easier to use.